# How to check number has no fractional part

Tags: apex

I am having an requirement. I am having Number field (NumberField_*c) in a custom Setting (MyCSObj*_c).

So I have to retrieve NumberField__c value from custom seting and need to check whether that number has any fractional part or not.

If that number doesn't has any fractional part then subtract that number of months from the end date and use that value for start date.

```
public with sharing class MyClassController {

public DummySObject__c dummyObj{get; set;}

public MyClassController(){
   dummyObj = new DummySObject__c();
   dummyObj.EndDateA__c = system.today();

MyCSObj__c appConstantSettings = MyCSObj__c.getInstance();

if(appConstantSettings != null 
&& appConstantSettings .NumberField__c!= null){
   Decimal interaction_Month = appConstantSettings.NumberField__c;
}

}
```

My questions are :
1) How to check the number is fractional or not
2) How to subtract any number from current date? (For example: Today's date : 2014-03-18 00:00:00; Number we get 1. So we have to reduce 1 month from current date.

Any help'd be appriciated.

Comment: You might want to change the 2 lines checking for null values from MyCSObj__c!= null to appConstantSettings!= null and also from MyCSObj__c.NumberField__c to appConstantSettings.NumberField__c

Comment: My Bad. I mistakenly mentioned the object itself for null check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) appConstantSettings.NumberField__c.scale() will get you the number of digits behind the comma for a numeric (decimal) field.

2) system.today().addMonths(-1) will get you 1 month before today

Comment: I want right hand side part of a decimal number.

For ex: 12.8 . I want 8.

Scale function will give you 12

Comment: No, in case of 12.8 then .scale() will give you 1. So in case Numberfield__c.scale() > 0 then it's fractional, else not.

Comment: @guy Presume you meant appConstantSettings.Numberfield__c.scale()?

Comment: @Keith you're right, thanks. I updated my answer and also made a comment to the poster to update the code fragment

Comment: @guy : What should be the value of appConstantSettings.Numberfield__c, so that it won't be considered as fractional ?

Comment: @guy : Let's say I am getting a decimal number 1.0. I want to get that 0. How I'll get that part?

Comment: There is no direct method but you can make use of the round() method by doing the following: 10 * (appConstantSettings.NumberField__c - appConstantSettings.NumberField__c.round(RoundingMode.DOWN))

Comment: @guy : 1 last help. Can we get left hnad side number of a decimal part.
ex: 1.5 will give 1; 2.3 will give 2

Comment: you can reuse this part: appConstantSettings.NumberField__c.round(RoundingMode.DOWN)